New 'Role' column based on values
I am looking to have a new column created called ' Role' to show the persons role in the company. People can change roles and the role is based on the cost centre and site they are at.
Dataset below:

I am looking to have a new column created to show the Role of the person based on their cost centre and site. E.g Emp 123456 should be showing as role ' Customer Services' as cost centre is 225 and site HO. Previous to this, emp was 'Finance' as cost centre was 101 and site UK etc...
Thanks!

A column where - in a query, or in a new/existing view? Assuming the mapping from cost centre and site to role is in another table you haven't shown, you can just join to that. If you mean you want it as an extra on this table then that's messy and unreliable, and probably a mistake.

Hi - you haven't actually asked a question. What have you tried and what specific issue are you facing? Also, please don't use images, as no-one can copy your data to try out a solution; instead use editable text formatted appropriately

You'll like want to create a new table that has the columns: Cost_Centre | Site | Role so you can maintain the relationship between these entities. Once that is complete then you will need to pivot this table so it's Emp_No | Cost_Centre | Property_Value and join to your new table.

One option is to create a cte with SITE/COST mappings to roles (if you don't have it already) and join it to your table data twice (once for SITE and once for COST CENTRE). Take care of validity dates too.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (EMP_NO, PROPERTY_CODE, PROPERTY_DESC, PROPERTY_VALUE, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO) AS
        ( Select 123456, 'SITE', 'Site', 'UK', DATE '2019-09-03', DATE '2022-09-30' From Dual Union All
          Select 123456, 'COSTCTR', 'Cost Centre', '250', DATE '2019-09-03', DATE '2020-06-10' From Dual Union All
          Select 123456, 'COSTCTR', 'Cost Centre', '101', DATE '2020-06-11', DATE '2022-09-30' From Dual Union All
          Select 123456, 'SITE', 'Site', 'HO', DATE '2022-10-01', DATE '9999-12-31' From Dual Union All
          Select 123456, 'COSTCTR', 'Cost Centre', '225', DATE '2022-10-01', DATE '9999-12-31' From Dual 
        ),

roles cte should be something similar to this:
  roles (ID, SITE_VALUE, COST_VALUE, ROLE_NAME) AS
    ( Select 1, 'HO', '225', 'Customer Services' From Dual Union ALl
      Select 2, 'UK', '101', 'Finance' From Dual Union ALl
      Select 3, 'UK', '250', 'Some other role' From Dual 
    )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select      s.EMP_NO, s.PROPERTY_CODE "SITE_CODE", s.PROPERTY_VALUE "SITE_VALUE", s.VALID_FROM "SITE_FROM", s.VALID_TO "SITE_TO", 
            cc.PROPERTY_CODE "COST_CODE", cc.PROPERTY_VALUE "COST_VALUE", cc.VALID_FROM "COST_FROM", cc.VALID_TO "COST_TO",
            r.ROLE_NAME
From        roles r 
Inner Join  ( Select * From tbl Where PROPERTY_CODE = 'COSTCTR' ) cc ON(cc.PROPERTY_VALUE = r.COST_VALUE)
Inner Join  ( Select * From tbl Where PROPERTY_CODE = 'SITE' ) s 
                  ON( s.EMP_NO = cc.EMP_NO And
                      s.PROPERTY_VALUE = r.SITE_VALUE And 
                      cc.VALID_FROM >= s.VALID_FROM And cc.VALID_TO <= s.VALID_TO
                    )
Order By    s.EMP_NO, s.VALID_FROM, cc.VALID_FROM

/*      R e s u l t : 
    EMP_NO SITE_CODE SITE_VALUE SITE_FROM SITE_TO  COST_CODE COST_VALUE COST_FROM COST_TO  ROLE_NAME        
---------- --------- ---------- --------- -------- --------- ---------- --------- -------- -----------------
    123456 SITE      UK         03.09.19  30.09.22 COSTCTR   250        03.09.19  10.06.20 Some other role  
    123456 SITE      UK         03.09.19  30.09.22 COSTCTR   101        11.06.20  30.09.22 Finance          
    123456 SITE      HO         01.10.22  31.12.99 COSTCTR   225        01.10.22  31.12.99 Customer Services    */

